# Difference between a hibernate transaction and a database transaction done using sql queries?

Tags: sql, hibernate, transactions

Is there a difference between the two?
For example within a hibernate transaction we can access the database, run some java code and then access the database again. We can't do that within a transaction done via SQL can we? Is this the difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 2 directly relate to each other - a Hibernate transaction maps to and controls the JDBC (database) transaction.

You can do the same thing with direct JDBC / SQL, without Hibernate - though you'll need to call [`Connection.setAutoCommit(false)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setAutoCommit%28boolean%29) to get started.  Otherwise, by default, a commit is called after each statement - making each statement run in its own transaction.

Some additional details are available at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html.